# Finding locally and globally closing loops in a graph with toroidal topology

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have a two dimensional square lattice (with periodic boundary) with loops on it, i.e., collections of connected links which form closed loops. The lattice has the topology of a 2-torus and therefore there are two distinct classes of loops. "Locally" closing (contractible to a point) and "globally" closing (not contractible) ones. The loops may overlap and intersect, so there is in general no unique way of assigning a given link to a single loop.

I need an algorithm (suitable for implementation on a computer) which can give me a (necessarily not unique) list of local and global loops and the links they contain. It shouldn't be too hard to come up with one oneself, but there certainly must be some existing thought on it and I would be glad, if someone can point me to a source.